# AdaptiveCard with "mailto" Action.OpenUrl no longer works

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams, adaptive-cards

On Microsoft Teams, we have a bot that sends AdaptiveCard message activities to users through the Microsoft Bot Framework REST API. Sometimes, the AdaptiveCard contains an Action.OpenUrl. With regular links such as https://google.com it works as expected, but since about one month, URL parameters with a `mailto` url such as `mailto:recipient@domain.com` no longer work: the message is sent, the button appears but clicking it does not do anything.

Sample request:

POST https://smba.trafficmanager.net/emea/v3/conversations/<conversation_id>/activities

Body:

```
  "recipient": {
    "id": "29:1uuzUvFTkcseXZ1Q2wOva1inGkpH1SqbHwqdXjG8MhUa8mkFsdUnvrgn4FnPbX8CwBl_GwDHSQGIlRSPKczwUFg"
  },
  "type": "message",
  "attachments": [
    {
      "contentType": "application/vnd.microsoft.card.adaptive",
      "content": {
        "type": "AdaptiveCard",
        "version": "1.0",
        "body": [
          {
            "type": "ActionSet",
            "actions": [
              {
                "type": "Action.OpenUrl",
                "url": "mailto:antoine.chopin@heyaxel.com",
                "title": "TEST"
              }
            ]
          }
        ],
        "actions": []
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: [etil](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17479543) posted an [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70066595) saying "Seems to be working by now (November 2021). I got it to open the email in Outlook from MS Teams."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently openSafeUrlMT does not allow **mailto** urls. we already have a backlog feature request on this. Concern team is working on this.

Comment: Is there a tracker on this I could subscribe to so I can stay updated?

Comment: @Konrad - This feature will be tracking internally. We will update you if it gets updated but we do not have any ETA to share.